# Querying JSONPath using conditions on parallel node

Tags: jsonpath, jsonpath-ng

My JSON has specific name values and id's associated with the name values in a parallel node (don't ask me why but I didn't design the JSON). I would like to retrieve name values based on a specific id. For example, I would like to retrieve the `NAME - ABC Creations` based on the `ID - 50200df3-7476-4bab-86ab-1aae4c097095`

I am using `jsonpath-ng` library for python

```
Full JSON:

{
   "Document":[
      {
         "Fields":[
            {
               "Type":{
                  "Text":"NAME",
                  "Confidence":97.65931701660156
               },
               "ValueDetection":{
                  "Text":"ABC Creations"
               },
               "PageNumber":1,
               "GroupProperties":[
                  {
                     "Types":[
                        "RECEIVER_SOLD_TO"
                     ],
                     "Id":"50200df3-7476-4bab-86ab-1aae4c097095"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Type":{
                  "Text":"NAME",
                  "Confidence":92.77919006347656
               },
               "ValueDetection":{
                  "Text":"Hardwood Industries, Inc."
               },
               "PageNumber":1,
               "GroupProperties":[
                  {
                     "Types":[
                        "VENDOR_REMIT_TO"
                     ],
                     "Id":"844e1bf2-6adb-43fc-af41-bb26844bffe6"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Type":{
                  "Text":"NAME",
                  "Confidence":93.58846282958984
               },
               "ValueDetection":{
                  "Text":"HARDWOOD INDUSTRIES, INC."
               },
               "PageNumber":1,
               "GroupProperties":[
                  {
                     "Types":[
                        "VENDOR"
                     ],
                     "Id":"1f7ec071-8c24-4160-979a-3c44d6884d55"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I am able to retrieve all the name values using :

```
$.Document[*].Fields[?(@.Type.Text=='NAME')].ValueDetection.Text

Output is:

[
  "ABC Creations",
  "Hardwood Industries, Inc.",
  "HARDWOOD INDUSTRIES, INC."
]
```

If I query based on the Id I don't get the name:

```
$.Document[*].Fields[*].GroupProperties[?(@.Id=='50200df3-7476-4bab-86ab-1aae4c097095')]

Output:

[
  {
    "Types": [
      "RECEIVER_SOLD_TO"
    ],
    "Id": "50200df3-7476-4bab-86ab-1aae4c097095"
  }
]
```

Any suggestions or help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use nested queries.

```
$.Document[*]
   .Fields[?
     @.GroupProperties[?
       @.Id == '50200df3-7476-4bab-86ab-1aae4c097095'
     ]
   ]
 .ValueDetection.Text
```

(one-liner)

```
$.Document[*].Fields[?@.GroupProperties[?@.Id == '50200df3-7476-4bab-86ab-1aae4c097095']].ValueDetection.Text
```

The first few segments `$.Document[*]` get you into the `Fields` array.  Next, you want to start searching for items.

The outer query finds all of the objects with `GroupProperties`.  Because this isn't being compared to anything, it forms an "existence test," meaning that if any values are returned, the node the query applies to is selected.

The inner query refines the outer query to only objects within the `GroupProperties` array which have the appropriate `Id` value.

Once you've identified the outer set, you can just select the values you want with `.ValueDetection.Text`.

---

Nested queries aren't universally supported, so you may need to check with the implementation you're using, however this does conform to the [pending JSON Path spec](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-jsonpath-base-21.html).

You can play with this at https://json-everything.net/json-path (the playground for my .Net implementation).

Comment: Thank you - this is indeed very interesting. What if I need to include the filter on `Type.Text=='NAME'` - is there a way to include that in the nested filter?

Comment: I tried using an `&&` operator but it did not work - `$.Document[*].Fields[?@.GroupProperties[?@.Id == '50200df3-7476-4bab-86ab-1aae4c097095' && @.Type.Text=='NAME']].ValueDetection.Text`

Comment: Solved it - `$.Document[*].Fields[?@.GroupProperties[?@.Id == '50200df3-7476-4bab-86ab-1aae4c097095'] && @.Type.Text=='NAME'].ValueDetection.Text`